# FullCalendar - Removing the dot in event

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

How do I remove the dot on the left side of the time started in events? Can't seem to find it in the documentation of FullCalendar

[image]

Full JS code for the FullCalendar setup (this is all under a JQuery function statement)

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({      
    defaultDate: "{{ $month_year->format('Y-m') }}",
    defaultView: 'month',
    displayEventTime: true,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    eventWidth: "100%",
    eventHeight: "100px",
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
    },

    eventClick: function(jsEvent) {
        $('#m_modalCal_' + jsEvent['id']).modal("show");
    },

    events: [
        @php foreach($trainings as $training)
            { 

                $dateTimeStart = $training->start_date->format('Y-m-d ').Carbon::parse($training->start_time)->format('H:i:s');
                $dateTimeEnd = $training->start_date->format('Y-m-d ').Carbon::parse($training->end_time)->format('H:i:s');
        @endphp
                {
                    id: "{{ $training->id }}",
                    title: "{{ $training->title }}",
                    start: "{{ $dateTimeStart }}",
                    end: "{{ $dateTimeEnd }}",

                    @if($training->type_id == 1)
                    color: "#C0FFEE",
                    textColor: "black",
                    @elseif($training->type_id == 2)
                    color: "#E8D091",
                    textColor: "black",
                    @else
                    color: "#A491E8",
                    textColor: "black",
                    @endif

                    @if($training->status == 2)
                    color: "gray",
                    textColor: "black",
                    @endif
                },
        @php } @endphp
    ],
  })
```

Comment: As you can see from https://fullcalendar.io/ this is not the default look of fullCalendar's "month" view. So it seems you have customised it with some extra CSS and/or JavaScript (or perhaps you've employed a theme which does that). That's why you can't find anything in the documentation. Therefore to solve your problem, you need to modify that custom code. We can't see exactly what you did, so we can't really help you any more precisely than that.

Comment: @ADyson I've added the script

Comment: Right, but as you can see from [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/17/) the code above does not create the dots. Like I said before, somewhere you've got some custom JS and/or CSS which is creating those. You need to find that and remove it. Based on the information given, I can't tell you where it is or what you need to do, but if you right-click the dot and then Inspect it with your Developer Tools in the browser, it'll hopefully lead you to it.

Answer (score 14):

In fullcalendar v5, you can set [eventDisplay / event.display](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay) to display as block, which does not show the event dot.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({      
  //...
  eventDisplay: 'block',
  //...
})
```

Also: see the [upgrade notes (v4 to v5) about daygrid events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#event-rendering).

Or, explicity hide the dot:

```css
#calendar .fc-daygrid-event-dot {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this was true when ADyson posted his comments, but as you've pointed out, the dots *are* part of the default display for timed events in the month view in v5. This solution reverts the display back to the older style with no dots. I had the same issue as the OP, but once I'd established that the dots were the correct behaviour I removed the CSS class I had setting a background colour for events to get the out-of-the-box style.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to accomplish this by setting the `color` of each event to the color-code of its category. Setting `color` will make the event's `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` equal the same value, effectively hiding the dots, I think.

See also [fullcalendar bug #3393](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3393).

Comment: These dots are not part of the default look and feel of fullCalendar in the month view. The bug you've linked refers to the "list" style view which is generated entirely differently...it's not really relevant here. OP has customised the display somehow, so the solution to removing the dots is to remove the bit of custom code which generates them.